# How do i remove slashes in mkdir command?

Tags: bash, shell, mkdir

As you know, you cannot use the mkdir command with slashes.

I am creating an automation and what i did first, was to nmap every IP Addresses i chose, "192.168.1.0" for example, as the first argument.

then, make a folder named the first argument, which is "192.168.1.0" = $1 ==> ./script.sh 192.168.1.0

but, I want the user to put the IP Address like this: "192.168.1.0/24".
How do i use the mkdir command now to still create a folder named "192.168.1.0" without /24 as the first argument still?

I tried many variations with sed commands.
I hope i was clear enough to explain myself.

Comment: Does Kali use bash, or some more basic shell? If it uses bash, try `mkdir "${1%/*}"`. The `%/*` part means "remove something matching `/*` from the end of the argument".

Comment: The linked duplicate's answers suggest quite a lot of potential solutions; that said, the one I would use is `mkdir "${1%%/*}"`

Comment: BTW, there's no need to duplicate information from your question's tagging in its title. (Also, generally speaking, tagging should be limited to things that can help put it in front of the right experts; the fact that the data came from nmap has nothing to do with how you process it for mkdir, f/e, and someone who knows nmap well will have no better ability to answer this question than someone who's never heard of it)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a possible solution using `cut`:

```
#!/bin/bash
dir_name=$(echo "$1" | cut -d '/' -f 1)

mkdir -v "$dir_name"
```

Output: [example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PXNAG.png)

This obviously doesn't validate the IP address, for that you could do some parsing with a regex.

Comment: I need the folder name stays as the IP Address itself without /24 or _24.

This is a great example of how i need it to be looks like:
https://i.imgur.com/5CUHS6b.png

Comment: Not sure if I have understood at this point, so you want to create a folder named from example 192.168.1.0 when you pass 192.168.1.0/24? You want to remove the "/24"?

Comment: Exactly what i want to do.

Comment: @Oded I've edited the comment with a possible solution